# SQL Server Performance issue (MEMOBJ_RESOURCEXACT)

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server Performance issue due to high Memory utilization

```
SQL Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR) (KB4583463) Standard Edition (64-bit)  
Min Memory:0, Max Memory:4096, System Memory:8 GB
```

SQL server performance is getting slow down day by day on a Dell T320 Server.

We run DBCC CheckDB command as part of daily database backup Job and the DBCC command goes to suspended mode when the system runs for ~14 days continuously. Database size is 2.5GB.

Other database applications fails to execute after the DBCC command failure

We got the memory utilization by using the queries below

```sql
SELECT TOP(5) [type] AS [ClerkType], SUM(pages_kb) / 1024 AS [SizeMb] FROM sys.dm_os_memory_clerks  WITH (NOLOCK) GROUP BY [type] ORDER BY SUM(pages_kb) DESC
```

Result:

```
MEMORYCLERK_SQLSTORENG 2214
MEMORYCLERK_SQLBUFFERPOOL 441
MEMORYCLERK_SOSNODE 52
MEMORYCLERK_SQLCLR 32
USERSTORE_SCHEMAMGR 25
```

and the highest memory utilized memory object is MEMOBJ_RESOURCEXACT

```
MB Used     type
2212        MEMOBJ_RESOURCEXACT
```

We want to narrow down to the exact object which is holding this memory. Looks like the memory is not getting released by this memory object.

What is the way to get more details about MEMOBJ_RESOURCEXACT memory object?.

Comment: 4GB if memory is *nothing* for a SQL Server. If memory limitations is an issue, you should really be installing more RAM for a host that is limited to that little.

Comment: What is the SQL Server's process memory?  3rd party code can allocate memory outside the SQL Server memory clerks.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-process-memory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: For what it's worth, `XACT` is the standard internal cryptic abbrevation for "transaction", so this apparently concerns "transaction resources" of some sort.

Comment: @Larnu, Increasing the memory would be a workaround option but we can't guarantee that it will resolve the issue. We think that increasing the memory will be just like delaying  the occurrence from 14 days to say 14+x days.

Comment: Any possibility of a memory leak, similar to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3034615-fix-memory-leak-occurs-when-you-run-dbcc-checkdb-against-a-database-in-sql-server-2014-e0544ee4-f9c2-587f-d56b-9d31710eecb5

Comment: Why DBCC checkdb on daily basis along with database backup? Once in a week or twice would be sufficient. What is the size of database against which you are running dbcc checkdb?

Comment: Size of the DB:2.5 GB